# Will file.delete() method block thread?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a piece of code to delete some files on Android platform, and I'm wondering if the file.delete() method blocks until the file is actually deleted or not.

Comment: I wouldn't assume any particular implementation, meaning it certainly could.

Comment: it returns `boolean` value indicating if file was deleted or not - so the answer is: yes, it will block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it blocks the calling thread until either the File is successfully deleted in which case it returns true, or an error occurs in which case, the exception is internally caught and false is returned.

Based on the [Android documentation for File#delete](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#delete())

> Returns boolean   true if and only if the file or directory is
>   successfully deleted; false otherwise

A cursory look at the [implementation in the AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/io/File.java#311) (albeit a bit old) confirms this.